# How can I get a .MTL file to show on an .OBJ model I imported in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, import, obj

I've downloaded & imported several .OBJ models into Blender but they don't always import with the textures automatically in place, even though the model came with them. Here's an example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yQeQQ8ImENWWYyb0oxYWZMVjQ/edit?usp=sharing

I assume this is due to the presence of an .MTL file, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the Blender Internal render engine your model will import with the texture already applied.

[image]   [image]

If you are using Cycles you will not get any textures applied to the mesh whatsoever. In this case you will need to manually assign the textures to your shader.

Comment: Is that still the case? Is it a bug in Cycles? I find it easier to use Cycles for some tasks, but it is impossible to work with if it does not import the material.

Comment: Cycles still does not import the material.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [link](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?394600-Materials-Specials-amp-conversion) to the add-on. Unzip it in your add-ons folder and use it in blender. You might have to run blender as administrator.

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?394600-Materials-Specials-amp-conversion