# How can I get my texture to show on an Imported file?

Tags: texturing, import

So I import a file from turbosquid but it doesn't have the texture. How do I add the texture?
I already tried to do texture on it but doesn't work.

Comment: What fileformat has the file you are importing? Is it already a blender file? And does the texture not show in the render or are you just using solid shading in the viewport (which does not show textures by default)?

Comment: Why is this question not suitable? Include steps you already tried, upload your blend-file, etc. refer to http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: It was a obj file and it doesn't show when it's rendered.

Comment: See also, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/how-can-i-get-a-mtl-file-to-show-on-an-obj-model-i-imported-in-cycles?rq=1

Comment: @ColorTheory Share a link to the file.

Comment: http://storage2.turbosquid.com/Download/index.php?ID=820608_13097437