# Textures and colors not imported from OBJ file when using Cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to import a bunch of models from OBJ files (with their MTL files) to a blender scene that I have.
When using Blender Render the materials and textures are imported successfully.
But when using Cycles Render the material names are imported, but not their actual data.

This behavior is also noted by [How can I get a .MTL file to show on an .OBJ model I imported in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/how-can-i-get-a-mtl-file-to-show-on-an-obj-model-i-imported-in-cycles)

Is there a workaround for this? I prefer to use Cycles for my rendering (for using GPU devices, and node control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, cycles does not yet support importing materials due to the great difference in the way materials are designed in cycles.

There are some plugins such as blender material to cycles node converter

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Material/Blender_Cycles_Materials_Converter

I would recommend importing while under blender internal renderer, than either hand creating the cycles nodes, or using this plugin to generate them.