# Color disappears after changing render engine from Blender internal to Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, import, vertex-colors

I am importing a colored .ply file, which is basically an output of a 3D scan. When I import it in Blender internal, and tick the checkbox "Textured Solid" in the menu, the color shows up on the 3D model. No issues so far. Now when I change it to Cycles, I am not able to see the colors. Colors on the object change to the default grey.

I have checked the following questions which were previously asked:

[Textures disappear when the rendering engine is switched to cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39371/textures-disappear-when-the-rendering-engine-is-switched-to-cycles)

[Textures and colors not imported from OBJ file when using Cycles render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24019/textures-and-colors-not-imported-from-obj-file-when-using-cycles-render)

They talk about plug-in which converts materials or textures added in Blender Internal to be compatible with Cycles. But in my case, there are no materials that I am adding. The texture associated with .ply is not shown in the materials or texture section. I am not using any UV maps also. So, I am not able to figure out how to turn on the texture associated with the ply file in the Cycles Render. There is no .mtl kind of a material file with .ply

Comment: Have you tried importing into cycles directly?

Comment: Yes. Nothing changes. It is all grey.

Answer (score 1):

In the materials panel, go to the Options section, and set the checkbox for **Vertex Color Paint**.

Comment: My materials panel looks like this
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_NsSAqhnSwRYkctX0U2XzFQQk0/view?usp=sharing

Can't really see options section or anything of that sorts

Comment: Add a material, then it should show up.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help. Figured it out.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, if it helped ;-) @RickRiggs, Adding that detail to you answer would be really helpful