# Import from Trnio: losing texture

Tags: texturing

I have a problem. I am trying to import a mesh that I scanned with the mobile phone 3d-scanning software Trnio, into Blender 2.79.

From Trnio I downloaded a folder with one .ply file and one texture file in .jpg

The two are linked propperly, because if I open them in Meshlab, the obj gets displayed correctly with its texture.

Once I open it in Blender, the obj gets displayed WHITOUT the texture. (I am in cycles)

If I unwrapp the model and apply the texture it does not match at all and the texture gets displayed completely wrong.

Thats how my texture file looks like:
[image]

And this is the model unwrapped on the texture:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?
Happy for any ideas, help!

Thanks

Comment: Related link: [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/how-can-i-get-a-mtl-file-to-show-on-an-obj-model-i-imported-in-cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/how-can-i-get-a-mtl-file-to-show-on-an-obj-model-i-imported-in-cycles) Imported .obj files do not create a cycles materials. You need to recreate it manually.

Comment: Object should have had its own UV map which come from the original application. Unwrap shown on screenshot above obviously won't match that texture.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: I had the same problem. Solution: Meshlab (free) you import the ply there, then export it as obj, then import the obj and its material file into blender

Comment: Solution: Meshlab (free) you import the ply there, then export it as obj, then import the obj and its material file into blender. Copied from the comments, thanks @pierre-vinandy, you saved me a lot of time.